# Get random ID from variable - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
FOR v_i IN 1..vt_all_executors.COUNT LOOP
  IF NOT vt_executor_total_work_count.EXISTS(vt_all_executors(v_i)) THEN
    RETURN vt_all_executors(v_i);
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Good afternoon. Here is a piece of code that exactly selects those IDs that are needed and outputs the value (the first ones) via the RETURN function. The question is how to make it choose this ID randomly. I know the function `dbms_random`, but I still do not have how to apply it in the experience.

If necessary - here is the complete request - https://pastebin.com/EsdXAd3p

Answer (score 1):

The following code returns random number between 0 and 10000000, without decimal places:

```
FOR v_i IN 1..vt_all_executors.COUNT LOOP
  IF NOT vt_executor_total_work_count.EXISTS(vt_all_executors(v_i)) THEN
    RETURN ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.value(0, 10000000));
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

If you need decimal places to be included in possible outputs, remove ROUND function.
If you need some other min or max possible value, change input values to DBMS_RANDOM.value(min, max) function.

If, on the other hand, you need to return random value from one of yours' *vt_all_executors* values, then you will need this:

```
-- piece of code before the loop
SELECT MAX(rwn) 
  INTO v_random_max
  FROM (SELECT aex.column_value AS user_id,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY aex.column_value) rwn
          FROM TABLE(vt_all_executors) aex );

FOR v_i IN 1..vt_all_executors.COUNT LOOP
  IF NOT vt_executor_total_work_count.EXISTS(vt_all_executors(v_i)) THEN
    v_random_chosen := ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1, v_random_max + 1));

    SELECT user_id 
      INTO v_random_return
      FROM (-- same inner select as before the loop, with the same order by
            SELECT aex.column_value AS user_id,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY aex.column_value) rwn
              FROM TABLE(vt_all_executors) aex )
     WHERE rwn = v_random_chosen; 

    RETURN v_random_return;
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

What I am doing in this second code example is connecting every one of your vt_all_executors values to a number. The smallest vt_all_executors value is attached to number 1, next is attached to number 2 and so on, with the largest vt_all_executors value attached to v_random_max).

Then I pick a random value between 1 (smallest vt_all_executors value) and v_random_max (largest vt_all_executors value), as I can't connect to them directly (because there are gaps between those vt_all_executors values).

Having thus the number attached to exact vt_all_executors value, I collect that exact vt_all_executors value and return it with *RETURN v_random_return*.

Comment: Nope. You can see, that he is returning executors.He should randomize them, not to take just random value.

Comment: I haven't understood your question as needing random value from vt_all_executors. I now edited my post. See if that helps. You would need to declare some more local variables.

Comment: @ВикторБайкер I'll be active for just an hour from now.
If last edit doesn't help you, please tell me (with feedback) before then so I can help you further :) If not, I can continue tomorrow..
Of course, if my post answered your question, I'd appreciate it if you would tag it as correct..

Comment: Still, when you are causing `ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1, v_random_max));` value can't be right. All IDs are holding in `vt_all_executors(v_i)` variable. So he should randomize that list(as i understood, `v_i` is an value).

Comment: `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` Gives the random value within the range, but there is not min and max value.

Comment: @ВикторБайкер What I am doing in my edit is connecting every one of your vt_all_executors values to a number. The smallest vt_all_executors value is attached to number 1, next is attached to number 2 and so on, with the largest vt_all_executors value attached to v_random_max). Then I pick a random value between 1 (smallest vt_all_executors value) and v_random_max (largest vt_all_executors value), as I can't connect to them directly (because of gaps between those values). Having thus the number attached to exact vt_all_executors value, I collect that exact vt_all_executors value and return it.

Comment: @ВикторБайкер I just added +1 to ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1, v_random_max + 1).
About min and max values, from Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i998095